# JGraphx : How to avoid adding edges over each other?

Tags: edges, jgraphx

I'm working on an application using jGraphx and I want to know how to avoid creating edges over each other.

When I add 2 edges between 2 vetexes, the 2 edges are above eatch other..

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : That's what I get, those are 2 edges with the labels : "dist = 1" and "dist = 4" above each other.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "edges above each other"? And do you mean you're adding two separate edges between the same two vertexes?

Comment: Yes, two separate edges between the same two vertexes. I added a picture showing what I'm getting.

Comment: Your graph is not wrong. The graph `visualization` is the one that is not correct.

Comment: Yes, that's why I posted the question, I want to know how to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done easily:

```
    new mxCircleLayout(graph).execute(graph.getDefaultParent());
    new mxParallelEdgeLayout(graph).execute(graph.getDefaultParent());
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any of your source code it's hard to offer specific details, but in general, what you need to do is get the graph's stylesheet, and then modify the edge related parameters.  An example is:

```
    mxGraph mxgraph = new mxGraph();
    Object parent = mxgraph.getDefaultParent();
    mxgraph.getModel().beginUpdate();
    mxStylesheet stylesheet = mxgraph.getStylesheet();
    Hashtable<String, Object> style = new Hashtable<>();
    stylesheet.putCellStyle("ROUNDED", style);

    Map<String, Object> vertexStyle = stylesheet.getDefaultVertexStyle();
    vertexStyle.put(mxConstants.STYLE_FILLCOLOR, "#FFFFFF");
    vertexStyle.put(mxConstants.STYLE_STROKECOLOR, "#000000");
    vertexStyle.put(mxConstants.STYLE_AUTOSIZE, 1);
    vertexStyle.put(mxConstants.STYLE_SPACING, "10");
    vertexStyle.put(mxConstants.STYLE_ORTHOGONAL, "true");
    vertexStyle.put(mxConstants.STYLE_SHAPE, mxConstants.SHAPE_ELLIPSE);

    Map<String, Object> edgeStyle = stylesheet.getDefaultEdgeStyle();
    edgeStyle.put(mxConstants.STYLE_EDGE, mxConstants.EDGESTYLE_ORTHOGONAL);
    edgeStyle.put(mxConstants.STYLE_SHAPE, mxConstants.SHAPE_CURVE);
    edgeStyle.put(mxConstants.STYLE_ENDARROW, mxConstants.ARROW_CLASSIC);

    ...set up your edges and vertices here, where the last parameter is "ROUNDED" (the name of the stylesheet)

    mxgraph.getModel().endUpdate();
```